# Xcode console log littered with [IconManager] messages

Tags: xcode, console

While developing my SwiftUI app, my console log is filled with the following noise:

```
2022-03-19 11:13:21.522465+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Chn Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.526159+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Chn Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.527175+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi INTL PostOfficeHorn Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.527227+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi INTL PostOfficeHorn Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.527764+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi CZE Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.527817+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi CZE Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.527864+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi CZE Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.527897+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi CZE Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.529265+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi CZE Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.530308+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi INTL PostOfficeHorn Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.530626+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Poi CZE Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:21.531288+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Prague Custom Icons
2022-03-19 11:13:23.679844+0100 AppName[AppNo] [IconManager] No config pack found for key Localized Chn Icons
```

The "AppName[AppNo]" shows the name of my app, followed by some numbers in brackets.

The above is about 1/3 of such messages from only a very short run. It's very annoying, what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Just wondering if you ever figured this out? Getting the same messages.

Comment: Nope, no solution so far

Comment: I had a bunch of these and they went away when I upped my app's iOS deployment target.